# Equatable with enum - Swift

Tags: swift, enums

How can I validate equal with below source code?

```
enum ErrorAPI: Equatable, Error {
    case CannotFetch(String)
}

func ==(lhs: ErrorAPI, rhs: ErrorAPI) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.CannotFetch(let a), .CannotFetch(let b)) where a == b:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how this code works? Or do you want to have a different solution of equation?

Comment: Yes. -> Are you asking how this code works

Comment: @ Joakim Danielson. I am getting error in my func and when I use from your code let err1 = ErrorAPI.CannotFetch("abc") let err2 = ErrorAPI.CannotFetch("abc") print(err1 == err2), say me Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Error' and 'ErrorAPI'

Comment: Which Xcode/Swift version are you using? In Swift 4 and later, the compiler synthesizes the `==` operator for the Equatable conformance automatically, even for enums with associated values.

Comment: I thought that wasn't what you asked about so I deleted my comment. I did not get any error though unless I remove the `==` func _and_ the protocol conformance. This was in a on-line playground using swift 5.

Comment: Ok. Thank's a lot. Resolved my problem with your help.  let err1 = error as! ErrorAPI
                    let err2 = ErrorAPI.CannotFetch("Cannot fetch orders")
                    print(err1 == err2)

Comment: Please don't describe the problem in the comments, but [edit] your question and add a [mcve].

Comment: Why this method `func ==(lhs: ErrorAPI, rhs: ErrorAPI) -> Bool` is outside the `enum`? It should also be `static` as per `Equatable` conformance. BTW, You don't need this method to implement as in current swift version, enum and struct don't need explicit implementation of equivalence method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The enum case `CannotFetch` has an associated value of type String. That means, when the enum case is set to `CannotFetch`, a specific String is associated with that case. Read through the [official Swift documentation about Enumerations](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID148) if you need to understand Associated Values.

The `func ==()` method is a so called `Equivalence Operator`. You can read more about it in the [official Swift documentation about Advanced Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AdvancedOperators.html#ID42).

When comparing two enums, lets call them `enumOne` and `enumTwo`, this function is implemented to be able to compare those two enums if both cases are `CannotFetch(String)`.

Example:

```
let enumOne = ErrorAPI.CannotFetch("Hi")
let enumTwo = ErrorAPI.CannotFetch("Hello")

if enumOne != enumTwo {
    print("They are not equal!")
} else {
    print("They are equal")
}
```

The line `case (.CannotFetch(let a), .CannotFetch(let b)) where a == b:` works as follows:

1. This case is only proceeded if both, enumOne and enumTwo, are set to the case `CannotFetch(String)`
2. Take the associated value (=String) of the left hand sided enum, i.e. `"Hi"` and assign it to the new constant `let a`.
3. Take the associated value (=String) of the left hand sided enum, i.e. `"Hello"` and assign it to the new constant `let b`.
4. Additionally, Check if the values behind the constants `a` and `b` are equal, i.e. Check if the Strings `Hi` and `Hello` are equal.
5. If all this is true, execute the code block in the case, i.e. `return true`